# How to search text in one table using keywords from another table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use bigquery to search text in TABLE A by using keywords in TABLE B. I must register, per each row found in TABLE A, which keywords it matched in TABLE B. I would be most grateful for the standardSQL bigqury code that uses the input below to generate the expected result below

INPUT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE project.dataset.keyword AS
SELECT 'foo' as keyword
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'bar';
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE project.dataset.txt AS
SELECT 1 AS key, 'I love foo' AS text
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'I love foo and bar'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'I love bar'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 ,'I love something else';

EXPECTED RESULT:
    1, foo;
    2, foo;
    2, bar;
    3, bar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select key, keyword
from `project.dataset.txt` t
cross join `project.dataset.keyword`
where regexp_contains(text, keyword)
```

if to applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]